# File size of an Excel Workbook increases every time I create a new pivot table and save the file

Tags: excel, vba, filesize

I have a vba macro that creates a pivot table based on some data in an input sheet. Every time the macro runs, the old pivot is deleted and a new one is created.

The problem I'm facing is that every time I save the file after running the macro, the file size increases by roughly 14MB.

This is how I delete the old pivot table:

```
For Each pivot In reportSht.PivotTables
    pivot.TableRange2.Clear
Next pivot
```

My theory is that some part of the pivot isn't being deleted but I can't seem to put my finger on what.

Comment: Does using `SaveAs` instead of `Save` reduce the file size? • Also read [Remove Pivot Cache to Save Space](https://trumpexcel.com/reduce-excel-file-size/#Remove-Pivot-Cache-to-Save-Space) Use `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count` to check the number of PivotCaches in your workbook. • This might be helpful too: [Pivot Cache in Excel – What Is It and How to Best Use It](https://trumpexcel.com/pivot-cache-excel/)

Comment: I'll look into the Pivot Caches but I've also found out that I'm not deleting the connections, which has greatly reduced file size and stopped the file size from growing. I'll post an answer with my solution later.

Comment: If you delete the connection then the cache will be deleted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. When I create the pivot tables I also add connections, since I need to display the number of unique entries in the pivot table:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 "WorksheetConnection_" & inputDataArea, "", _
    "WORKSHEET;" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\[" & ActiveWorkbook.name & "]" _
    & inputSht.name, inputDataArea, 7, True, False
```

Where `inputDataArea` is a String with the range used by for the pivot table. My problem was, that I was not deleting these connections when I was deleting the pivot table. So a new connection was being added every time the macro was executed.

I added this piece of code to also remove any connections that are no longer needed after removing the pivot table:

```
Dim connection As Object

For Each connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If connection.name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then connection.Delete
Next connection
```

The file is still large but manageable and most importantly it's not growing anymore.

Thanks to [Pᴇʜ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C) for suggesting that I remove pivot caches and pointing out, that these are deleted along with the connections.